# NSFetchedResultsController sectionNameKeyPath equivalent for EKEventStore fetched events from iPhone Calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, ekevent

NSFetchedResultsController with property name as sectionNameKeyPath allows retrieving managed objects by Core Data retrieved as group sections. I am looking for a similar method of doing this for fetching Calendar Events via EKEventStore proxy class, to achieve a group by date to create an agenda view of event grouped by date. I am currently doing this in code wondering if there is a way to do this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSFetchedResultsController grouping is special and specific to Core Data objects. You'll had to do any grouping logic for EKEventStore data manually.

Comment: but from a performance perspective isn't it better to take the events and put them into core data?

Comment: If you want to replicate all the EKEventStore data into Core Data then yes, you can exploit the grouping functionality. Just keep in mind that you'll have to keep the data in sync regularly.

Comment: So what i am looking for is some benchmarking on performance and what would account for best practice

Comment: Core data is always going to be slower because it persists to disk, unless you are using an in memory store. Writing more code and doing it on EKEventStore data is going to be faster.